# combine multiple rows into a single row in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have 3 column in my test table like

```
ID | m_id    | S_m_id                                 
---------- --------------
1  |  1      |    1                  
1  |  2      |    3                  
1  |  3      |    4                  
1  |  5      |    6                  
2  |  1      |    1                  
2  |  2      |    3                  
2  |  3      |    4                  
3  |  5      |    6
```

I want to merge column 2 and 3 based on column 1 into one single row. And the result should be like

```
ID | merge_id                                 
---------- --------------
1  |  1,1;2,3;3,4;5,6                  
2  |  1,1;2,3;3,4                  
3  |  5,6
```

Comment: This is called string aggregation -- search SO for many examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function that you need is `listagg()` with does string concatenation when aggregating.  You also need to first concatenate the ids together:

```
select id,
       listagg(m_id || ',' || s_m_id, ';') within group (order by m_id) as merge_ids
from test t
group by id;
```

By the way, the result data is incorrect (because the id is the same on all three rows).  This probably accounts for the downvote.

EDIT (in response to comment):

You have two separators in the original example, one is comma (between ids) and one is a semicolon (between rows).  You can replace either with `'|'` to get a pipe separator.

Comment: hi gordon thanks...it worked...but how can i merge id column with separator |.

Comment: want to merge now 1 column and 2nd column with pipe separtor

Comment: select id,test.nextval
       listagg(m_id || ',' || s_m_id, ';') within group (order by m_id) as merge_ids
from test t
group by id; Using this query i m getting ora - 02287 sequence number not allowed here.